# Extracting both the full match, and the last token match in a regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, token

I have a little interesting issue here. I have a plaintext URL coming from Excel and I need to change it to an HTML URL with a unique body. Here is the regex code for javascript:

```
text = text.toString().replace(/=hyperlink\(([@\\\w\s\(\)-\.\/]+)\)/g, "<a href='file:///$1'>$1</a>");
```

This works perfectly fine for what it does. Example, text is:

```
=hyperlink("\\share\folder\log\2013\13-05-13\13-05-13.txt")
```

regex turns it into

```
<a href="file:///\\share\folder\log\2013\13-05-13\13-05-13.txt">\\share\folder\log\2013\13-05-13\13-05-13.txt</a>
```

However, I need the inner HTML to be just the text file name:

```
<a href="file:///\\share\folder\log\2013\13-05-13\13-05-13.txt">13-05-13.txt</a>
```

To further complicate the matter, the original text the regex is going through is not a single occurrence. It is an entire spreadsheet with 100's of rows that contain this. So the regex will be matching and replacing 100's of these strings in one operation.

Hopefully it is possible to get this all done in one regexp on the entire string, but I suppose I could loop through each line of the string first...

If there is no way to do this with one regex engine, what do you think the best approach is? (no PHP/Python/Server side. Just Javascript, HTML, Jquery, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use this regex:

```
=hyperlink\("([@\\\w\s\(\)\-\.\/]+\\([^"]+))"\)
```

And this new replace:

```
<a href="file:///$1">$2</a>
```

I'm not sure how your regex was working, but I added the quotes in the regex and replaced the single quotes by double quotes in the replace. Revert those if need be.

[Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/dW4jG7)

Comment: Great demo site!!! Wow that was amazing. Okay I got the regex working just how I want with this `text = text.toString().replace(/=hyperlink\((.+\\)([^\\]+)\),/gi, "<a href='file:///$1\$2'>$2</a>,");`

Comment: @EricS That's awesome! :) And yup, I like regex101 over the other ones I've come across so far. One because of the array of things you can use, two because of the description and three because of the replace :)